# Web scraping prices from an aggregator sites

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

This might be very simple for some. but I can't get my head around it. I'm trying to extract prices and other info from a website.

[Link](http://www.yatra.com/hotels/hotels-in-coorg/club-mahindra-madikeri-coorg)

I'm using Rvest to do the scraping. I'm not from CS background so I'm not able to understand the class input to the html nodes that will be used. I'm looking in the section 'Similar Hotels' for prices of similar hotels. my code attempt is below. Do let me know the shortcomings in my code.

```
    url='http://www.yatra.com/hotels/hotels-in-coorg/club-mahindra-madikeri-coorg'
    
index <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("#carousel_one")

count <- index %>%
    html_nodes("span") %>%
    html_text() %>% 

location <- counts %>%
    html_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text()

type <- counts %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_text()
```

I have got a turn around but it is for an individual node. I want to get all the nodes in a single command.

My code is obviously not right. Ideally I am seeking an explanation of the methodology involved in finding the right tags and class for such info.

I have read the TNC conditions already.

Comment: seems to me you've trying to scrape business directories, read [this](http://scraping.pro/business-directories-scrape-tips-tricks/) then.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin Will read that but i got throught the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the code, but again a little logic is missing.

The code is:

```
index <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("#container .crousel")

fetch <- index %>%
    html_nodes("span") %>%
    html_text()
```